# Multiple `to: ` in Dante socks proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, socks, dante

I'm trying to have multiple hosts using the `to: example.com foo.com` with multiple hosts. Right now it fails to restart, and only one host is allowed. I've searched the documentation everywhere how to do this and can't find anything.

https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/client.html

```
##
## SOCKS command rules
##
#rule processing stops at the first match, no match results in blocking

#block communication with www.example.org
# block {
#        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: www.example.org
#        command: bind connect udpassociate
#        log: error # connect disconnect iooperation
# }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in the current 1.4.x versions of Dante, so you will need to have one rule for each unique "to:" or "from:" address.

socks pass { from: 0/0 to: example.com }
socks pass { from: 0/0 to: foo.com }

Multiple to/from-addresses in one rule will be supported in Dante 1.5.0.